# Can't raise modal PyQt5 dialogs made by QtCreator

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt, qt-creator, pyqt5

Okay. Here goes. I've got this app I'm building using PyQt5, the QtCreator, and a bunch of handwritten logic. It needs to have multiple custom (modal) dialogs that do work on filesystem files. I've read every tutorial I can find, so it's just time to bite my pride and ask.

The main app is called "joe.py" and its opening lines look like this. I've tried to wire up the first dialog box, one that reads and sets a bunch of config variables.

```
from Ui_newdialog import Ui_configDialog as Form

from Ui_joe_mainwindow import Ui_mainWin

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_mainWin()


def show_config(self):
    dialog = QDialog()
    dialog.ui = Form()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
    dialog.show()

# attempt to hook up first button
ui.configButton.clicked(show_config(ui))

# below here is the setting of a bunch of QtCreator form
# variables, some dynamic display jazz, and so on.
```

The config dialog box is called the same way, with a wrapper (showconfig.py) that fills in all the QtCreator stuff and does the logic work of reading and writing the configuration. Here's its opening stanza:

```
from Ui_config_dialog import Ui_configDialog

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_configDialog):
        QDialog.setObjectName("Dialog")

        # Set labels, populate text boxes, write config file
        # blah blah blah
```

Each one of these dialog boxes is going to be a step in the overall operation of the program. I'm splitting it up for the sake of usability and so that I can take advantage of the neat, clean layout work I can do in QtCreator.

It can't be impossible to raise a modal dialog with the push of a button. I don't care about the customary return values (accept, reject), because I'll be doing all the important work inside the dialog window code itself.

Please help me get these windows hooked up. I've been at this for two days straight and not made any progress.

While I wait for some help, I need to go see why my Pycharm remote debugging has gone bad...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've got everything correct as it should be, but I get an error of 

`TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable`

I neglected to merntion, or maybe clarify, that I want to open another "regular" .py file (showconfig.py) with this button click.

Comment: `ui.configButton.clicked.connect(lambda: show_config(ui))`.

Comment: That opened the dialog, all right. But it just opened as a blank form. The dialog has code to pre-populate a handful of text boxes and check boxes to reflect the existing configuration. Is it possible to pop up the dialog _and_ run the embedded code?

Comment: Your second code example is junk. If you use an unedited gui module generated by pyuic, it will work.